# How do I use the node editor for material?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I was using the node editor in an earlier project and I found it fairly easy to follow, so I opened up a new one to experiment. I added a plane, created a material and went to node editor, where I was completely dumbfounded. The nodes I expected to see with the diffuse and output weren't there, and the material changed to black. Not only that, but I couldn't even add any shader node!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't use material nodes in Blender Internal. Try changing your mode to "Cycles" in the drop down that has "Blender Render" in it right now.

Comment: Ah, thanks that fixed it immediately! ^-^

Comment: while the blender internal has some limitation in the node editor over the cycles one, you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the material in the material slot.

[image]